# What does it mean by "actions are taken" in ECMAScript 5?

Tags: javascript, ecmascript-5

Here is the excerpt.

> 15.2.2.1 new Object ( [ value ] ) # Ⓣ
> When the Object constructor is called with no arguments or with one argument value, the following
> steps are taken:
>
> If value is supplied, then If Type(value) is Object, then
>
> If the value
> is a native ECMAScript object, do not create a new object but simply
> return value.
>
> If the value is a host object, then actions are taken
> and a result is returned in an implementation-dependent manner that
> may depend on the host object.

I'm just wondering what's the different between passing in a Native Object and passing in a Host Object to the Object constructor. In other words, if I call new Object(document), what happens behind the scene? I cannot see any difference by checking the return value.

Thanks in advance.

Comment: all it means is that the host must take care of converting host objects. typically, nothing "happens".

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What the excerpt is saying is that if `value` is a host object such as a `Document`, then it's up to the implementation to decide what `new Object(value)` will do ("actions are taken […] in an implementation-dependent manner that may depend on" `value`) and what value it will return ("a result is returned in an implementation-dependent manner that may depend on" `value`).

Even if `value` is a host object, most of the time `new Object(value)` will do nothing and return `value` (just as if it were a native object). And in the specific case of a `Document`, I would strongly expect that behavior. But the ECMAScript standard does not require this. (And the DOM specification, which defines the `Document` type, doesn't seem to require it, either.)

Answer (score 1):

For the native objects : javascript has **not to create the new object** and simply returns the values.

But for the host objects : javascript first **create a new object** and then only returns the values.

That's what the spec is saying. Hope you understand!